# Small margin left when div width defined to be 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a fairly simple website and so far all I have is the top title bar. For some reason, there is a small margin on the left side. Any idea why and how to fix it?

[image: The website on internet explorer]

```css
.headbar {
  background-color: #117FF2;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='headbar'>
  <h1> Title </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: try using left: 0; in .header class properties.

Comment: or `body{margin:0;}`

Comment: that gap is the default body margin. Either method works, I would recommend the usage of a body margin reset.

Comment: Also set `* {box-sizing: border-box;} ` it will help you to minimize box model related issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's probably caused by the default margin of the `body` element.

Try this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```